# How to apply gradient to element with correctly display in IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, less

I want apply gradient to my element. I use less to do it.

For IE9 I use the following css:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=@FirstColour, endColorstr=@SecondColour)";
```

where @FirstColour =#b7d4ee and @SecondColour=#7a9eca;

It is the gradient like this:
[image]

But in IE9 with css-style defined above, I see the gradient like this:
[image]

When page load in IE9 browser, my less isn't compiled (not sure why) and render into:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@FirstColour', endColorstr='@SecondColour')
```

How to get normal gradient display in IE9 with less using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the gradient generator [here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)
It provides all gradient solutions for every browsers, including IE. Instruction is explained there

Comment: this is IE9 Gradient Bug. I find information that I can use only svg to do gradient in this IE version. But I can't use it because I use less variables. Epic fail :(

Answer (score 0):

Try creating gradient from here:

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/default.html